# Is there a GUI for Apache, MySQL just like XAMPP for Windows?

Tags: apache2, mysql, lamp

I know how to install Apache, MySQL, PHP ..etc

But I do not want Apache and MySQL to start at boot time. I also do not want to start them manually using the terminal.

I am looking for a GUI program for this purpose just like XAMPP for Windows

If you have never used XAMPP for Windows, here is a screenshot the GUI for it:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the XAMPP control panel GUI for Ubuntu by running

`sudo /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py`

See http://bhargavg.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/xampp-control-panel-gui-in-ubuntu/ for more info.

Comment: But I did not install XAMPP. I installed apache2, php5, mysql-server using apt-get.

Comment: Why not install XAMPP then? It seems like it will provide exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: First, I did not know about the GUI. I thought XAMPP is only web based on Linux. So I started looking for a similar GUI without the need for XAMPP. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The xampp control Panel has a default GUI for linux, No need to create it, its already there. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

For 64 bit version or

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux.run
```

For 32 bit version.